# adb respawns when emulator running even after kill-server

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I'm trying to run an Android emulator on my Mac and debug it from a Windows VM running on the Mac. The apparent roadblock is that the adb server process on the Mac (the one listening on tcp 5037) keeps being created again a few seconds after I run `adb kill-server`.

This occurs as long as the emulator is running, including if I launch it from the command line, and I'm guessing is why `adb` on my Windows machine can't connect. I installed the emulator using Visual Studio for Mac but it is not running.

The adb process on the Mac seems to have been started by `qemu-system-i386` (the emulator process) as I observe the process list in Activity Monitor: two `adb` processes momentarily appear and one has that as the parent process and then it is gone, leaving the other one around to listen on 5037.  Is there a way I can prevent this from happening or at least make adb stay dead when I say kill-server?

Comment: just remove (or rename) the `adb` binary

Comment: Are you sure it isn't respawned by android studio? I've observed this on my mac quite vividly. Shutting AS down worked like a charm in my case.